# Custom Card not showing as in design

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been trying for some time now to fix layout.I have a custom cardview like this :[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G1fb.png) 
This custom card is inside a fragment this one:

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/recycle"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which itself is inside a viewpager.The problem is when I run the app my custom card becomes full width,I have tried even with RelativeLayout still isn't as I have in my design layout.

Custom_Card Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/job_post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff">...
```

Can sb help me?Thanks in advance

Comment: Give margin to you item layout

Comment: I have and it doesnt display when I run the app @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: give match parent to your recyclerView width

Comment: let me try @SaurabhBhandari ,I think I have tried but who knows

Comment: nope @SaurabhBhandari still not working

Comment: post your item layout as well

Comment: just did @SaurabhBhandari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CardView` as your Parent layout in item layout as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen4"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/job_post"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Give `width` of `RecyclerView` `match_parent` in your activity or fragment. 
Thanks , I hope its work for you

Comment: Yep it helped me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use card view in linear layout and then set margin like below:-

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cardview Demo"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will help you and you can set margin of cardview or your required width to cardview

Comment: Okay. Thanks @saurabhBhandari, to update my knowledge.